# Pursue pending sneeze

Tags: personal-care, health

During cold season I'm most likely to catch colds and often I sneeze.

There are times that when I'm about to sneeze but it doesn't go through and it bothers me. Is there any lifehack for that?

PS I'm not sure what tags to use, open for suggestions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looking at a bright light will often precipitate a sneeze that "hangs" like this.

Comment: how about areas that doesn't really have that much bright light?

Comment: What I originally heard was to "look at the sun", which actually causes you to tip your head back at a 45-degree angle.  For me, this activates the sneeze again. So the "bright light" isn't needed.

Comment: @BrettFromLA Wow, is it really because of the head angle that will re-trigger the sneeze? Any reliable source for the claim? or maybe I should try that trick next time. :)

Comment: @threeFatCat The first time I heard the "look at the sun" trick, someone else in the same group told me it's really about tipping your head back a bit. I've used the trick every since, and it works for me. It makes sense that whatever was tickling your nose starts to roll backwards when you tip your head, tickling your nose again, and your body will sneeze to expel it. (That's my theory anyway!)

Comment: Great! Never thought of that idea. I will try it, I supposed to make this open still because of looking into the sun is the common trick but I should accept the answer. Hopefully, if there is, someone will post a different answer or idea that will do the trick.

Comment: This is known as the "Photic Sneeze Response" and is a generic trait which I have. I'm afraid if you don't have it, this will not work for you. Apparently, about 30% of people have it. It's not about the angle of the neck but a sudden increase of light intensity. Sometimes, I need to flick my eyes back and forth at the sun in order to activate it. An artificial light works almost as well, but you then have to engineer the circumstances a bit more carefully - looking away from the light, moving very close to it, then looking direct at it for a short time.

Comment: "genetic", of course....

Comment: I second @Lefty's comment, it is true that the Photic Sneeze Response is only present in some people. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e69XZJ9DEj0